# 'in' & '==' operators gives unexpected output when using together in a expression without parenthesis in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, operator-precedence

```
>>> print(True in [True] == True)
False
>>> print((True in [True]) == True)
True
>>> print(True in ([True] == True))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    print(True in ([True] == True))
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
>>>
```

Why is the 1st line gives us False. I'm using Python 3.8.3

Comment: Someone just asked the same question like 5 minutes ago. Is this from something?

Comment: @Carcigenicate thank you for your suggestion. I get it from it. Now it's clear